# jQuery and JavaSctipt form validation: Password field param undefined and password-confirm ok

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form here when you press "Click To Test Signup" : http://www.problemio.com/test.php

If you enter all the fields, it gives you a password error.  The reason for that being that on the JS validation side, the password field somehow can't be retrieved.  Here is the part of my form:

```
 <p>
     <label for="name"><span>Password (5+ Characters):</span></label> <input type="password" id="user_pass" name="user_pass" >
 </p>
 <p id="password_error" style="display:none;">
    <span class="error">The password must be over 5 characters.</span>
 </p> 
 <p>
     <label for="name"><span>Password Confirm:</span></label> <input type="password" id="user_pass_check" name="user_pass_check">
 </p>
 <p id="password_confirm_error" style="display:none;">
    <span class="error">The passwords must match</span>
 </p>
```

and here is how I retrieve the parameters:

```
    var password = $("#user_pass").val();       
    var pass_confirm = $("#user_pass_check").val();

    alert ("password: " + password);
    alert ("pass_confirm: " + pass_confirm);
```

the password confirm field actually gets the parameter ok, but the password field is always undefined or empty.  Any idea why that is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is supposed to be about form validation but I don't see any form validation code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page has two password fields with same ID 'user_pass', one in signup form and another in login form, Use different IDs and there 'll be no issue.

Comment: @GeekedOut, use the W3 HTML validation service... it catches things like this.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate id usage problem, you used same id more than one time in same html. Change your elements id.